# Im looking to filter my query to get all names with the relation of ID

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to have this output from my query:

```
CODE  NAME  MANAGER
 1    John  Ely
      Paul
      Elsa  Anahid
 2    Raul  Ely
      Rosa  Paul
      Ahmad
```

How can I order in this way?

```
John,Paul and Elsa belogns to CODE 1  
Raul,Rosa Ahmad  belong to CODE 2
```

I tried but i obtain this:

```
CODE  NAME  MANAGER
 1    John  Ely
 1    Paul
 1    Elsa  Anahid
 2    Raul  Ely
 2    Rosa  Paul
 2    Ahmad
```

OR this:

```
CODE  NAME  MANAGER
 1    John  Ely
 2    Rosa  Paul
```

The query:

```
SELECT ad.CODE,em.NAME,em.MANAGER
FROM employess em INNER JOIN
     address ad 
     ON ad.CODE = em.CODE 
GROUP BY ad.CODE;
```

Comment: Your first result set is what SQL produces.  You should do the modifications in the presentation layer.

Comment: You want to get desired output only by sql query? Or you don't mind using java for it?

Comment: @GolovPavel I dont know if my desired output is possible to do only with a sql query because i tried in differents ways, so if not is possible i could use some code java

Answer (score 1):

As Gordon Linoff suggested, indeed better to do modification in presentation layer.

Hovewer it is also possible to achieve with SQL.

```
SELECT
  IF(
    em.NAME = (select ems.NAME from employees ems where ems.CODE = em.CODE order by em.NAME LIMIT 1),
    em.CODE,
    ''
    ) as CODE,
  em.NAME,
  em.MANAGER
FROM employess em
INNER JOIN address ad ON ad.CODE = em.CODE
ORDER BY em.CODE, em.NAME;
```

This will only work if names are unique in table employess, otherwise better to compare uniq IDs in a subquery.
And yeah, this subquery is adding unnesesary load to database. So if performance is important - keep a query simple, and process CODE field in java.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the simple POJO class:

```
public class Employee {
    private Long code;
    private String name;
    private String manager;

    \\ constructor, getters and setters ...
}
```

and SQL query:

```
SELECT ad.CODE,em.NAME,em.MANAGER
FROM employess em INNER JOIN
     address ad 
     ON ad.CODE = em.CODE
```

You can make query using JDBC or other JDBC addons (Spring Data, Hibernate etc.) After that, you will have a list of `Employee`s and you can simply group employees by code:

```
List<Employee> employees = // Recieving employees from database
Map<Long, List<Employee> groupedEmployeesByCode = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCode()));
```

I think, that it's possible to do this using native SQL, but I can't come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate `ditto` formatting but you'd better format the output in the app.

```
SELECT IF(@ditto = (@ditto := ad.CODE)
         , ''
         , ad.CODE
         ) AS CODE
     , em.NAME
     , em.MANAGER
 FROM employess AS em 
 JOIN address   AS ad ON ad.CODE = em.CODE 
WHERE ((@ditto := 0) OR 1)
ORDER BY ad.CODE;
```